# Templates is not getting listed in Child pages

Tags: aem

I am working in Adobe AEM , I have a query reg restricting templates to set of pages.

1.Consider Template AA and BB. I have added Template AA as allowed templates in TEMPLATE BB. But when i tried to create a Child page for the page created with Template BB ,Template BB alone is getting listed in list of available templates ,its not showing Template AA in the list?

Comment: When you say allowed templates, have you mentioned Template AA as `allowedParents` in Template BB or as `allowedChildren`?

Comment: I added allowed templates "cq:allowedTemplates":TemplateAA in jcr:node of TemplateBB

Comment: As far as I know, cq:allowedTemplates is set on the root page of your site and not on the template itself. i.e., it is set on the page's jcr:content and not templates.

Comment: no i have added to templates

Comment: That's what it didn't have any effect. Instead of cq:allowedTemplates change the property to allowedChildren in Template BB. Or remove it entirely and add the property allowedParents on Template AA

Comment: Can you put a Sample ? I coudnt get you. One more thing is that i am facing this issue for a only one templates all other templates its wrking fine for me with Cq:allowedtemplates

Comment: @KamalKannan Take a look at this - https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/templates.html#Template%20Availability

Comment: Thank You folks. Its Instance Cache problem. Even everything was perfect It didnt pick the properties. Later restarted it . Its working fine now

Comment: @KamalKannan Add you comment as answer, so that everyone could know this question is resolved.

Comment: Actually I added the property "cq:allowedTemplates" , but it didn't fetch the properties . Then Restarted the instance and again set the properties. It got worked

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple factors that go into deciding which templates are available. For the full details check out the **Template Availability** section of the [Templates documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/templates.html).

For your set up:

- The `cq:allowedTemplates` on the actual content page (or one of it's ancestors), should list Template AA
- The `allowedChildren` property on Template BB should list Template AA
- The `allowedPaths` on Template AA either does not exist, or it contains the path of the content page
- The `allowedParents` on Template AA either does not exist, or it contains Template BB